# Javascript implement deep filtering in nested json data

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following data structure

```
tasks = [{
   id: 1,
   name: "task1",
   subtasks: [
      {
         id: 4,
         name: "task2",
         subtasks: [{
            id: 11,
            name: "task to remove",
            completed: false
         }]
      },
      {
         id: 6,
         name: "task to remove",
         subtasks: []
      },
      {
         id: 7,
         name: "parent task to keep",
         subtasks: [{
            id: 11,
            name: "task to keep",
            completed: true
         }]
      }
   ]
},
{
  id: 44,
  name: "task to keep",
  subtasks: [{
    id: 55,
    name: "task to keep",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    id: 66,
    name: "task to delete",
    completed: false
  }
  ]
}
]
```

With unlimited level of nesting, only leaf tasks have the flag completed and I need to filter out only those tasks which are completed and keep them with their parents.

I look at lodash but it does not seem to have a deep filter. I am now thinking about using a tree traversal to filter out the tasks.

Is there an easy way to implement something like this with lodash ?

Comment: please add a wanted result and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted a lodash solution. I believe this recursive function does the trick.

```
function completed (task) {
    // if it is a leaf node, just return true when it is completed
    if (_.has(task,'completed')) {
        return task.completed;
    }

    // if it has subtasks, then use our filter on all the subtasks ...
    if (_.has(task,'subtasks')) {
        task.subtasks = _.filter(task.subtasks, completed);

        // ... and only return true if there are subtasks left after filtering
        return task.subtasks.length;
    }

}

console.log(_.filter(tasks,completed));
```

Comment: Note that this solution mutates the original array.

Answer (score 0):

well, what you want can be acheive by a recussive function, however (because you want easy solution) here is a solution with a callback as a second argument with `JSON.parse` and we will parse it from string; But, please note, easy dosen't always meant performance efficient!

```js
//your data
tasks = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "task1",
        subtasks: [{
                id: 4,
                name: "task2",
                subtasks: [{
                    id: 11,
                    name: "task to remove",
                    completed: false
                }]
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                name: "task to remove",
                subtasks: []
            },
            {
                id: 7,
                name: "parent task to keep",
                subtasks: [{
                    id: 11,
                    name: "task to keep",
                    completed: true
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 44,
        name: "task to keep",
        subtasks: [{
                id: 55,
                name: "task to keep",
                completed: true
            },
            {
                id: 66,
                name: "task to delete",
                completed: false
            }
        ]
    }
]

//solution
var finalTasks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tasks), (k, v) => {
    if (Array.isArray(v)) {
        return v.filter(u => u);
    } else if (typeof v === "object" && !(v.subtasks && v.subtasks.length) && !v.completed) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return v;
});

console.log(finalTasks);
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with 'k', 'v' and 'u' ? Short variables are not self explanatory